# Importing DLL's doesn't work the same (VS2003 to VS2010, multithreaded to multithreaded DLL)

Tags: c++, templates, dll

During a massive code update from a mix of VC6, VS2003, and VS2005, I am running into a problem where VS2010 doesn't behave like VS2003 did.  The application will scan a directory of DLL's and attempt to load them in one by one.  This is done here:

```
CConfigPlugin::CConfigPlugin(LPCTSTR szPluginName)
{
    ASSERT(szPluginName);
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(szPluginName));

    m_csFullpath = szPluginName;
    m_hModule = LoadLibrary(m_csFullpath);
    m_pInterface = (IConfigDllInterface *) NULL;
    pInterface pPtr = pInterface(NULL);

    if (m_hModule != NULL)
    {
        //  If we loaded the DLL get the interface pointer
        pPtr = pInterface(GetProcAddress(m_hModule, "GetInterface"));
    }
    if (pPtr != NULL)
    {
        pPtr(&m_pInterface);
    }
    else
    {
        ::FreeLibrary(m_hModule);
        m_hModule = HMODULE(NULL);
    }
}
```

All DLL's show as being loaded:
...
'GenConfig.exe': Loaded 'C:\src\Debug\config\GenLogonConfig.dll', Symbols loaded.
'GenConfig.exe': Loaded 'C:\src\Debug\config\GenReportConfig.dll', Symbols loaded.
'GenConfig.exe': Loaded 'C:\src\Debug\config\ImportConfig.dll', Symbols loaded.
...

Each DLL has an identical GetInterface implementation shown below:

```
CConfigDllInterfaceImpl<CParentDlg> gdllObj;

BOOL GetInterface(IConfigDllInterface **ppPtr)
{
    *ppPtr = &gdllObj;

    // Temporary edit to test if gdllObj is set to proper parent.
    CString name;
    name = gdllObj.GetDisplayName();
    // End edit

    return true;
}
```

With a template as shown below:

```
__declspec(selectany) UINT guiAdvise;

template <class T> class CConfigDllInterfaceImpl : public IConfigDllInterface
{
public:
    CConfigDllInterfaceImpl()
    {
        guiAdvise = RegisterWindowMessage(_T("GenConfig"));
        m_pDlg = NULL;
    }

    virtual LPCTSTR GetDisplayName() const
    {
        static CString csTemp;

        csTemp.LoadString(IDS_DISPLAY_NAME);
        return csTemp;
    }

    //  Can't be virtual because it uses the template T argument
    BOOL            DoModal(HWND hParent)
    {
        ASSERT(IsWindow(hParent));
        if (m_pDlg == (T *) NULL)
        {
            m_pDlg = new T(CWnd::FromHandle(hParent));
            return m_pDlg->Create();
        }
        else if (IsWindow(m_pDlg->GetSafeHwnd()))
        {
            m_pDlg->PostMessage(guiAdvise, eAdviseSwitchViews);
            m_pDlg->SetActiveWindow();
        }
        return TRUE;
    } // SNIP...
```

I can tell that my template isn't properly registering to its intended parent.  GetDisplayName just returns "".  My suspicion the cause of my problem is that I made a decision a month ago to change everything to Multithreaded DLL from Multithreaded.  These are all MFC projects and it seemed the simplest and easiest way to just use _AFXDLL and make everything properly compile and link.  All of the rest of my projects work fine, but I believe that because of the way this DLL is loaded:

CConfigDllInterfaceImpl gdllObj;

No longer works the way it used to.

So, question 1:  Is my suspicion correct?  Or am I completely offbase?
Question 2:  If my suspicion is correct, how do I work around this?  It isn't an option to go back to multithreaded at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you rebuild all of your DLLs with VS2010?

Comment: Yes.  All part of the same solution.

Comment: Ensure that your resources weren't lost in the update

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.  I can set breakpoints and view debug information in the DLL.  But if I set a breakpoint in VS2003, I can see all of the handles are properly referenced.  When I set the same breakpoint in VS2010, those handles are NULL'ed.  I've become more and more sure that the key lies in "CConfigDllInterfaceImpl<CParentDlg> gdllObj;".   This runs when the DLL is loaded.  But in VS2003, it was set to the settings of the Parent dialog as intended.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee - You were absolutely right.  Though it took me four days of searching and re-searching to finally get to the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have some time to get back to answering this.  Collin Dauphinee was correct in that it was a resource issue.  I don't know why VS2003 is different from VS2010, but the solution was very simple.

```
CConfigPlugin::CConfigPlugin(LPCTSTR szPluginName)
{
    ASSERT(szPluginName);
    ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(szPluginName));

    // Save off current Afx resource handle.
    HINSTANCE hCurrentAfx = AfxGetResourceHandle();  // <---  Didn't need to
                                                     // do this before.

    m_csFullpath = szPluginName;
    m_hModule = NULL;
    m_hModule = LoadLibrary(m_csFullpath);
    m_pInterface = (IConfigDllInterface *) NULL;
    pInterface pPtr = pInterface(NULL);

    if (m_hModule != NULL)
    {
        AfxSetResourceHandle(m_hModule);   // <--- here is where the resources
                                           // get properly set.  This is the
                                           // solution to the problem.

        //  If we loaded the DLL get the interface pointer
        pPtr = pInterface(GetProcAddress(m_hModule, "GetInterface"));
    }
    if (pPtr != NULL)
    {
        pPtr(&m_pInterface);
    }
    else
    {
        ::FreeLibrary(m_hModule);
        m_hModule = HMODULE(NULL);
    }

    // Now put Afx back.
    AfxSetResourceHandle(hCurrentAfx);
}
```

I hope this helps someone else.  I was stuck for days on this one.